# How do I convert a GPFeatureRecordSetLayer Feature Set to a Feature Class?

Tags: arcobjects, feature-class, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, geoprocessing-package, graphics

I have C# code to run a geoprocessing package that produces an output which is stored in a GPFeatureRecordSetLayer. Right now I have code that displays the result on the GUI when the job is complete . . .

```
private void _localGPService_JobCompleted(object sender, JobInfoEventArgs e)
 {
 ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor geoprocessorTask = sender as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor;
 geoprocessorTask.GetResultDataCompleted += _localGPService_GetResultDataCompleted;
 geoprocessorTask.GetResultDataAsync(e.JobInfo.JobId, "Output_Areas");
 }

 private void _localGPService_GetResultDataCompleted(object sender, GPParameterEventArgs e)
 {

 ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPFeatureRecordSetLayer gpLayer = e.Parameter as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPFeatureRecordSetLayer;
 foreach (Graphic graphic in gpLayer.FeatureSet.Features)
 {
 // Code to add graphic to map
 graphic.Symbol = this.Resources["InputPolygonSymbol"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.SimpleFillSymbol;
 graphic.Geometry.SpatialReference = _graphicsLayer.SpatialReference;
 _graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
 _map.ZoomTo(graphic.Geometry);
 }
 }
```

What I need to do is to iterate through each graphic and convert the graphic features to an ArcObjects IFeatureClass that I can write to a file geodatabase. In other words, I want to convert a Runtime object to an ArcObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer object to accomplish what I was trying to do, which was to write the resulting feature class that was created from running the gpk to a geodatabase location of my choosing. I had to grab the GPFeatureRecordSetLayer when the gpk was completed, and use that result to populate the feature class using the Local Feature Layer service. Here is my code . . .

```cs
// Initialize objects for manipulating result of running gpk
ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer arcGISLocalFeatureLayer;
public ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPFeatureRecordSetLayer _gpFeatureRecordSetLayer;

public void StartGeoprocessing()
{
    // start the geoprocessing package
    string geoObjectPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeGeoProcessorObject"];
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor gp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor(_localGPService.UrlGeoprocessingService + geoObjectPath);
    gp.OutputSpatialReference = new SpatialReference(4326);
    List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter> parameters = new List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter>();
    SubmitJobAsyncMethod(gp, parameters);
}

private void SubmitJobAsyncMethod(ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor gp, List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter> parameters)
{
    gp.JobCompleted += _localGPService_JobCompleted;
    gp.SubmitJobAsync(parameters);
}

private void _localGPService_JobCompleted(object sender, JobInfoEventArgs e)
{
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor geoprocessorTask = sender as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor;
    geoprocessorTask.GetResultDataCompleted += _localGPService_GetResultDataCompleted;
    geoprocessorTask.GetResultDataAsync(e.JobInfo.JobId, "Output_Result");//the name of the output in the model
}

private void _localGPService_GetResultDataCompleted(object sender, GPParameterEventArgs e)
{
    _gpFeatureRecordSetLayer = e.Parameter as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPFeatureRecordSetLayer;

    EditMyFeatureLayer();
}

private void EditMyFeatureLayer()
{
    // Get the Local Feature Layer service that is used for editing the Result feature class
    string mpkPath_features = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeEditMapPackageLocation"];

    LocalFeatureService localFeatureService = LocalFeatureService.GetService(mpkPath_features);

    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer = new ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer();
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Service = localFeatureService;
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Editable = true;
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.ValidateEdits = true;
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.LayerId = 0;
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.ID = "Result";
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Path = mpkPath_features;
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.DisableClientCaching = true;
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.AutoSave = true;
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Mode = ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer.QueryMode.Snapshot;
    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.ShowLegend = true;

    GraphicCollection aGCollection = arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Graphics;

    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Initialized += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Update();
    };

    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.UpdateCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        foreach (Graphic aGraphic in _gpFeatureRecordSetLayer.FeatureSet.Features)
        {
            aGCollection.Add(aGraphic);
            _map.ZoomTo(aGraphic.Geometry);
        }
        arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Graphics = aGCollection;
        arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.SaveEdits();
        _map.Layers.Insert(1, arcGISLocalFeatureLayer);

    };

    arcGISLocalFeatureLayer.Initialize();
}
```